# splitting the string as name, value pair in perl

Tags: perl

Suppose i have string result in json format as below.

```
{ "errorcode": 0, "message": "Done", "login": [ { "session_timeout": "1800", "token": "1370907977", "sessionid": "##F7A7E49F7FCFF35D3F821201CBF2F7CB5937E4AC99BF2AF74B508A1C8B3F", "username": "" } ] }
```

How can get a hash table from this like,

```
hash[errorcode] = 0;  
hash[message] = Done;
```

PS: without using any additional modules and using simple string functions.

Comment: *Please* use a module. This looks depressingly like [another let's-parse-Chomsky-type-2-with-Chomsky-type-3 question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). (That one's about HTML, but the same principle applies.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use JSON module for parsing json structures to perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $json_text = q({ "errorcode": 0, "message": "Done", "login": [ { "session_timeout": "1800", "token": "1370907977", "sessionid": "##F7A7E49F7FCFF35D3F821201CBF2F7CB5937E4AC99BF2AF74B508A1C8B3F", "username": "" } ] });
my $href = decode_json($json_text);

print $href->{errorcode}, $href->{message}, "\n";
```

Comment: Since my script should run on any linux system, which i don't know whether it contains JSON module or not. Then how to get {name,value} pair hash table.

Comment: @Kranthi if you're with perl 5.14, there is `JSON:PP`. If not you can take it to your project subfolder `lib/` from http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MAKAMAKA/JSON-PP-2.27202/lib/ and `use lib qw(lib); use JSON::PP;`

Comment: How can i get sessionid now?

Comment: `use use JSON::PP;` instead of `JSON`

Comment: Yes, i have used JSON::PP only, but if i use $href->{login}->{sessionid}, it is giving **Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at** error, so how to get that data. ?

Comment: `$href->{login}[0]{sessionid}` as wanted hash is first element inside array

Comment: I've been enjoying your nice regex answers, but on this one it's nice to see a non-regex solution +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the non-module solution would be to cut and paste the relevant code from [an existing  module](https://metacpan.org/source/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.59/lib/JSON.pm).

But that would be a **terrible** idea. Far better to just install the module.